# Get which .wsp deployed certain file in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

Is there a way to see which .wsp deploys a certain file in sharepoint?

I have 30 wsps and I need to find out which of them deployed a given file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows Explorer rename all of the .wsp files to .cab and you can see the files contained therein.  Rename them back to .wsp when you're done and they'll still function properly.